# c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file - with some Chinese or Javanese

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am getting the following compilation errors:**

4>c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: '䀀∀䤀渀挀氀甀搀攀倀愀琀栀猀䘀漀爀䴀甀氀琀椀刀愀挀欀䌀漀爀攀䰀椀戀⸀琀砀琀∀': No such file or directory
4>  ∀䐀㨀尀瀀㐀挀氀椀攀渀琀尀倀爀漀䄀甀搀椀漀尀搀攀瘀开瘀猀㄀㈀尀倀爀漀䄀甀搀椀漀尀堀倀氀愀琀昀漀爀洀尀䄀瀀瀀猀ⴀ䌀漀洀洀漀渀尀䌀漀搀攀尀吀栀爀攀愀搀猀尀圀䌀䔀爀爀愀渀搀䴀愀渀愀最攀爀⸀挀瀀瀀∀
4>c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: '∀䐀㨀尀瀀㐀挀氀椀攀渀琀尀倀爀漀䄀甀搀椀漀尀搀攀瘀开瘀猀㄀㈀尀倀爀漀䄀甀搀椀漀尀堀倀氀愀琀昀漀爀洀尀䄀瀀瀀猀ⴀ䌀漀洀洀漀渀尀䌀漀搀攀尀吀栀爀攀愀搀猀尀圀䌀䔀爀爀愀渀搀䴀愀渀愀最攀爀⸀挀瀀瀀∀': No such file or directory
4>  匀漀甀爀挀攀猀尀圀䌀䰀漀最最攀爀⸀挀瀀瀀
4>c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: '匀漀甀爀挀攀猀尀圀䌀䰀漀最最攀爀⸀挀瀀瀀': No such file or directory
4>  匀漀甀爀挀攀猀尀圀䌀䴀甀氀琀椀刀愀挀欀䌀漀爀攀⸀挀瀀瀀
4>c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: '匀漀甀爀挀攀猀尀圀䌀䴀甀氀琀椀刀愀挀欀䌀漀爀攀⸀挀瀀瀀': No such file or directory
4>  匀漀甀爀挀攀猀尀圀䌀䴀甀氀琀椀刀愀挀欀䌀漀爀攀开䄀倀䤀⸀挀瀀瀀
4>c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: '匀漀甀爀挀攀猀尀圀䌀䴀甀氀琀椀刀愀挀欀䌀漀爀攀开䄀倀䤀⸀挀瀀瀀': No such file or directory
4>  匀漀甀爀挀攀猀尀圀䌀䴀甀氀琀椀刀愀挀欀䌀漀爀攀开䄀甀搀椀漀⸀挀瀀瀀
4>c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: '匀漀甀爀挀攀猀尀圀䌀䴀甀氀琀椀刀愀挀欀䌀漀爀攀开䄀甀搀椀漀⸀挀瀀瀀': No such file or directory
4>  匀漀甀爀挀攀猀尀圀䌀䴀甀氀琀椀刀愀挀欀䌀漀爀攀开䄀甀搀椀漀䜀爀椀搀⸀挀瀀瀀

**Any ideas?

How can I fix the language settings?**

Comment: Are you sure the files exist in the right directory? Because `No such file or directory` looks pretty clear to me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solved.

There was an invalid flag in .vcxproj file.

```
<Link>  
    <AdditionalOptions>%(AdditionalOptions)</AdditionalOptions>  
</Link>
```

Problem dissapeared when flag was removed.

Comment: I had a similar issue that went away when I removed this as well.  It had to do with the version of VS I was using and the additional experimental options being passed in.  This page explains it: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/broken-warnings-theory/

Answer (score 3):

We had same issue when upgrading our solution from VS2005 to VS2012. Problem was inside vcxproj files. We had new line character in command line options. After removing it, our project compiled without any problem.

changed this

```
 <AdditionalOptions>/MP4 
/Zm200</AdditionalOptions>
```

to this

```
 <AdditionalOptions>/MP4 /Zm200</AdditionalOptions>
```

Comment: for some reason, xml tags were removed from my response it should be ' <AdditionalOptions>/MP4 newline /Zm200</AdditionalOptions>' to  '<AdditionalOptions>/MP4 /Zm200</AdditionalOptions>'

Answer (score 1):

> **Any ideas?
>
>   How can I fix the language settings?**

This is not a language issue. The compiler cannot open the files you want it to compile. Do those files exist? Are you invoking the compiler from the right directory?

Also, you might get better help if you call your source files `foo.cpp`, `bar.cpp`, and `baz.cpp`. I guesstimate 80% of potential answerers will have a hard time telling your files apart or discovering simple spelling errors in their names.

Comment: Well, 䌀 is probably `/`, so it isn't that hard at least to tell files apart :P

Comment: just from visual inspection of similarity, i would guess that those files are named [.cc]

Answer (score 0):

restart the Visual studio(VS2013) is worked for me.
As per my understanding , linking was improper, restarting will help to auto link and will resolve c1xx issues.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps to encounter this problem:
1. Unload your project
2. Open vcxproj or csproj file in notepad++
3. remove the entry from  -> 
4. Load the project and try to compile it.

This will solve your issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check also the `Additional Options` you specified in the `Command Line` tag of your project setttings. The compiler will treat none option arguments as source file.

I once specified `/MP 1 (which should be /MP1)` and the compiler complained that `C1083 Cannot open source file: '1': No such file or directory`.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem after removing an include only in the `.vcxproj.filters` file.

After removing it also from the `.vcxproj` file, it was fixed.