# msbuild interprets file names as chinese characters for some generated projects, not others

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I've been working on a cross-platform build system for our software stack. Specifically I'm working on the windows component of the build system.

We have a number of projects, each with a hand-coded .vcxproj. Some of the projects depend on each other, some depend on Qt.

My .vcxproj files work fine for three out of the five projects I've tried so far, but fail on the other two in a pretty fun way:

```
project\dir> msbuild /p:Configuration=Release /p:PropertyA=C:\path\to\project\root\ /p:Platform=x64 obj\project.vcxproj
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.0.30319.17929
[Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.18047]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 16.07.2013 11:13:43.
Project "C:\path\to\project\root\obj\project.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory "C:\path\to\project\root\obj\x64_Int\Release_DLL_Int\".
InitializeBuildStatus:
  Creating "C:\path\to\project\root\obj\x64_Int\Release_DLL_Int\project.unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
ClCompile:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\AMD64\CL.exe /c /I"include path A" /I"include path B" /Zi /nologo /W3 /WX- /sdl /O2 /Oi /D NDEBUG /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /D QT_CORE_LIB /D _WINDLL /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /MD /GS /Gy /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Fo"C:\path\to\project\root\obj\x64_Int\Release_DLL_Int\\" /Fd"C:\path\to\project\root\obj\x64\\project.pdb" /Gd /TP /errorReport:queue
          /nologo

        src\main\cpp\source_a.cpp src\main\cpp\source_b.cpp src\main\cpp\source_c.cpp ...
  ????????????????????????????????????
c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: '????????????????????????????????????': No such file or directory [C:\path\to\project\root\obj\project.vcxproj]
  ????????????????????????????????
c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: '????????????????????????????????': No such file or directory [C:\path\to\project\root\obj\project.vcxproj]
...
```

With one of those strings of question marks for every source file, one question mark per character in the source file path.

That's on the command line, but if I open the project in Visual Studio (2012) I can see the characters for what they really are:

```
error C1083: Cannot open source file: '猀爀挀尀洀愀椀渀尀挀瀀瀀尀...⸀挀瀀瀀': No such file or directory
error C1083: Cannot open source file: '猀爀挀尀洀愀椀渀尀挀瀀瀀尀...⸀挀瀀瀀': No such file or directory
...
```

(I've elided the real file names, sorry.)

Each character in the file name has been replaced [consistently] with a Chinese character. It's a 1:1 replacement with a consistent relationship between Roman and Chinese chars, i.e. `\` -> `尀` and `cpp` -> `挀瀀瀀`.

I've run msbuild with diagnostic verbosity and nowhere in the 12000+ lines of output before those error messages is there a Chinese character -- it lists the source files correctly multiple times before it fails.

Through the time-honored debugging technique 'commenting stuff out at random' I've discover that if I manually edit the vcxproj files that fail in certain ways the problem will go away, but linking will fail because I've commented out library paths or source files.

In both failing projects removing 4-6 source files (at random, though it's consistent in that commenting out the same four files will always either work or not) will fix it.
In the one that depends on Qt, removing the path to $(QT5DIR)/include/QtCore will fix the problem, but fail to link because it can't find Qt.

The source files are all ASCII encoded, and there doesn't appear to be any consistent formatting in the ones that fix the problem when removed.

I've tried this on three different computers, two Windows 7 machines and an 8.1 preview. It works fine on 8.1, but fails on both the Win 7 machines.

It doesn't seem to be related to the number of files in the project, because one of the projects that work has far more files than either of the non-working ones.

It doesn't seem to be a dependency issue, because only one of the non-working ones depends on Qt and the commonalities between the working and non-working ones seem to rule out inter-project dependencies.

I realize this is pretty out there, any Microsoft Gurus know what's going on?

**Question 1:** What am I doing wrong? What could possibly cause this behavior?

**Question 2:** Any ideas on what I can do to continue tracking down the problem?

**Updates:**

- If I run the ClCompile line on its own it actually tries to compile everything, but can't find standard libraries. I think that means this problem isn't happening in that case.
- I've found what I consider to be a workaround here: [c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file - with some Chinese or Javanese](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561861/c1xx-fatal-error-c1083-cannot-open-source-file-with-some-chinese-or-javanes) but I'm still hoping someone will answer with a real solution. Why does this happen? Why does removing seemingly random parts of the .vcxproj fix this? Is there an encoding detection heuristic that's misinterpreting my paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a Microsoft bug!

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/774527

So, for now I'm going to leave out newlines in AdditionalOptions (even though it worked for some projects...?)

Not happy about this as a solution, but it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing a text formatting error.  Backslash has a value of U+005C and the character that it's being transformed into has a value of U+5C00 (according to http://www.scarfboy.com/coding/unicode-tool?s=U%2B5C00 ).  The same problem is true for the "c" in cpp and I'm sure for the "p"s as well.

I'm not intimately familiar with what text encodings MSVC supports but I'd start with looking at the encoding and ensuring that they're all the same and then looking at anything that could be incorrectly transforming the files, say a program that believes it is operating on ANSI files instead of an extended encoding.  Your might be missing a byte or your wide character's byte order might be flipped.

Comment: wow, nice job picking up on the shift. I'm currently looking into this, not sure where it could be happening.

Comment: The fact that resaving the file fixes the alignment issue either means that your text editor detects the problem and corrects it or that it's actually valid but msbuild doesn't reading support it and your text editor doesn't support saving it.  And I've always found it useful to look at unexpected "garbage" data in a hex editor.  It's almost always useful for identifying what that data actually is.

Comment: Just resaving didn't fix it, even removing certain things didn't fix it. Removing stuff until it was fixed, then re-adding things and saving broke it again.

Anyway, found a sort-of-solution. Thank you so much, your suggestion was helpful in narrowing down the possibilities of what it could be.